# GAE Channel API - Channels Created Cost

Tags: google-app-engine, channel, channel-api

I have a paid app and can see the quota is 90,040 per day for channels created.

I have looked at all the pricing pages from cloud services and developer pricing pages and can not see any prices regarding the cost per channel created after the 100 free limit.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Channel this page only says the daily limit is "Based on your budget" but I do not see any costs anywhere on the web.

Am I to assume that I get 90,040 free per day for having a paid app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the pricing changed recently and that's why the documentation is a little confusing. It used to be that you paid a tiny amount for each channel (something like 0.0001 - don't remember how many zeroes).

Now this tiny charge is canceled. You are just paying for CPU & bandwidth that your channels are using. That's why it says according to budget.

It's the same story with Email, and various other APIs as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing. I'm fairly sure Channel API should be included in the last row in the resource billing table.

Comment: And, at long last, I did manage to get the pricing page fixed -- now Channel *is* explicitly included "in the last row in the resource billing page", i.e, as a resource incurring "no additional charge" (beyond CPU and bandwidth consumed). Sorry it took a while to get the fix officially published!

Answer (score 0):

It costs 10,000 micropennies to create a channel (or 100 channels per 1 cent, see [appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) for more).

See a more detailed answer to the same question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/uQFWM6F--hY

Comment: So rather than Google just showing you the cost of this service you have to setup some appstats thing that records just to find out how much it would cost you? Seems rather ridiculous.

Comment: @Craig, indeed it would be. Mihail's answer is now obsolete -- currently, as finally documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing, Channel is officially listed as "no additional charge" (beyond CPU and bandwidth).